# Hard drive physical read error, how to find out which files affected?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, data-recovery, bad-sectors

My HDD is starting to go bad.  So I'm cloning it to a new drive using HDDRawCopy.
In the process, there are several read errors (from bad sectors?).  The question is, how do I go about to finding out which files/dir those sectors are mapped to, so I can restore those selected files from backup?

```
7/21/2016 12:17:07 AM   Copying... 
7/21/2016 12:17:33 AM   Read Error occurred at offset 721,354,752;  LBA 1,408,896   (Data error (cyclic redundancy check))
7/21/2016 12:20:19 AM   Read Error occurred at offset 6,383,665,152;  LBA 12,468,096   (Data error (cyclic redundancy check))
```